# Execution timeout problem when trying to add new field

Tags: craft3, field, admin

I've been having some problems since I've updated yesterday to craftcms v3.4 (was 3.3). When I try to add a new field via the admin, it takes an enormous amount of time (almost 5min, had to raise the nginx timeout and php execution timeout) on my local dev setup. 
Amount of fields I have are pretty minimal for now. 
I'm running following craft plugins:

```
"aelvan/imager": "^2.3",
"barrelstrength/sprout-fields": "^3.5",
"clubstudioltd/craft-asset-rev": "^6.0",
"craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0",
"craftcms/redactor": "^2.4",
"mikestecker/craft-videoembedder": "^1.1",
"sebastianlenz/linkfield": "^1.0",
"verbb/navigation": "^1.2",
"verbb/super-table": "^2.3",
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.4.0"
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? Doesn't feel very manageable at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update all the existing plugin first and check the issue.

- Switch to dev mode ( check log `craft/storage/logs/web.log` )
- Deactivate all the custom plugin and check if the site performance again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some common steps to find the culprit.

1. Always work in [dev mode](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#devmode)
2. Enable Debug Tool­bar or read the brief tutorial by [nystudio107](https://nystudio107.com/blog/profiling-your-website-with-craft-cms-3s-debug-toolbar)
3. Disable all the custom plugins one-by-one.
4. Once development is done, switch to production mode and disable log.
5. Adjust `Mysql` and `Server` minimum configuration based on your `site load`.
6. There is no need to use multiple cache strategy.
7. Activate useful admin dashboard widget only.
8. On the entries page, activate the most useful `Table Columns` only. 
   [image: hestabit]
9. Check system report information in the dashboard, make sure all the suggested requirements are fulfilled.

[image: hestabit-sysreport]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the culprit is the Super Table plugin. Only noticed it after the update to 3.4.

Thank you for the useful advice!

Comment: If my suggestion helped you. You can mark it as a solution.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Did you come up with a fix for this? I think I just ran into the same issue

Edit: Nevermind, I found the github issue where they discuss this problem. https://github.com/verbb/super-table/issues/346